# How to solve Error 520 original error in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cloudflare

My Codeigniter package connected with Cloudflare. If my package connected with Cloudflare. It's not working and it shows "Error 520: Web server is returning an unknown error".[image: Error 520 original error]

Without Cloudflare it's working fine.

Comment: Write solution as an answer.

Comment: Rather than edit the question to add the solution, post it as answer! [Answering your own question is not forbidden](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208/4733879), but [officially encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). (there is even an option to answer the question directly at the [Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem behinds with Cloudflare does not process requests with HTTP headers that are over 32KB. If you are storing multiple/large cookies, beware, they may be truncated, which may prevent users from being able to visit your site and it works fine without Cloudflare.

> 520 error problem fixed by while using session stored in the database. and it's working fine with Cloudflare.

Session storage reference:- https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver

Answer (score 1):

I logged in, and it worked. Then, I logged out and tried to login again and I saw the 520 error you're talking about.

I think it has something to do with your redirect URL.

```
https://www.plac24.com/user/login?rdr=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.plac24.com%2F
```

As you're redirecting them to your website, do you need the http://?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add my fix for my 520 issue with Cloudflare.  I had a content security policy set up on my nginx server configuration in `nginx.conf`.

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com ;  
img-src 'self' https://*.ggpht.com ;
```

I had inserted a line break into this header and never noticed or cared because it worked on all browsers.  Removing my line breaks to look like the below resolved my issues.

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com ;  img-src 'self' https://*.ggpht.com ;
```

You probably won't run into the exact issue as me, but the lesson here is to check your headers and try to selectively remove them until you can isolate or rule out these as issues.  Hopefully this can save you $20 for a cloudflare support subscription.